# facebook.GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: python, facebook

I have been getting this error trying to print my friends list for awhile. I am fairly certain I am providing a token. Any idea's on this?

```
import facebook
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import urlparse
import subprocess
import warnings
import urllib2
import json
#https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
# Parameters of your app and the id of the profile you want to mess with.
FACEBOOK_APP_ID     = '{app_id}'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = '{app_secret}'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'my-id-number-here'
# Trying to get an access token. Very awkward.
oauth_args = dict(client_id     = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                  client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                  grant_type    = 'client_credentials')
oauth_curl_cmd = ['curl',
                  'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' +   urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)]
oauth_response = subprocess.Popen(oauth_curl_cmd,
                                  stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
try:
    oauth_access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(str(oauth_response))['access_token'][0]
except KeyError:
    print('Unable to grab an access token!')
    exit()
facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
# Print friends list.
profile = facebook_graph.get_object("me")
friends = facebook_graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]
print friend_list
```

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error cause you are using an access token not a user token.

The user token can be generated by using facebook developers

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Just click Get Token > Get User Access Token 
This does the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

Probably your short-lived access token has expired. You can check this via

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

and review the validity of the access token.